# Spivak, Differentiability (An Exercise)

Tags: calculus

I am working on a problem from Spivak, question 52b. I will type part a for reference as well since it may be relevant to the problem at hand. It is stated as follows:

> There is another form of L'Hôpital's Rule which requires more than algebraic
>   manipulations: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$. Prove this as follows.
>
> **(a)** For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a number $a$ such that $$\left|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-l\right| <\varepsilon\qquad\text{for }x>a.$$
>   Apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and $g$ on $[a,x]$ to show that $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|<\varepsilon\qquad\text{for }x>a.$$
>   (Why can we assume that $g(x)-g(a) \not=0?$)
>
> **(b)** Now write
>   $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$$
>   (why can we assume that $f(x)-f(a)\not=0$ for large x?) and conclude that 
>   $$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l\right|<2\varepsilon\quad\text{for sufficiently large }x.$$

For part b, which is where my troubles lie, I have dealt with the limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$ and I was able to conclude both are 1, and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}$ was dealt with in part a via Cauchy MVT. And we know that for large enough $x$ (say, $x>N$), $f$ is unbounded so we can infer that $f(x)-f(a) \not=0$ for large enough $x$. Now this is all fine, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where a $2\epsilon$ comes from. I have been playing with this for a couple days with no luck.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Well note that by assumption $g'(x) $ is non-zero after a certain value of $x$ say $a$ and by Darboux theorem it is of constant sign. Thus $g$ is strictly monotone in $[a, \infty) $ and that means $g(x) \neq g(a)$ if $x>a$. The other part is mostly the typical $\epsilon, \delta$ gymnastics which involves triangle inequality and some simple bounds for various terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, write down whatevver the hint says. You will have an expression of the form $|A(x)-l|$ for some $A(x)$. Use the first part and write $|A(x)-l|\leq |A(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}|+|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l|$ and try to work from there. Below are the details.

> \begin{align*}
> \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l\right|&=\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}-l\right|\\
> &=\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}+\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|\\
> &\leq\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\right|+\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|\\
> &=\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}-1\right|+\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|
> \end{align*}
>
> The term $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\right|$ gets close to $|l|$ (so it may be bounded by $|l|+1$), the term mutiplying it gets close to $0$, and the last term gets close to $0$ as well, so I'll leave the details to you

Comment: Thank you! Forgive me, since I must be missing something obvious, but I am still not seeing how a 2$\varepsilon$ pops out. Any hints?

Comment: For large $x$, we have $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|<1,$$ so $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\right|\leq |l|+1.$$ For $x$ sufficiently large, we also have $$\left|\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}-1\right|<\varepsilon/2(|l|+1)$$ and $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l\right|<\varepsilon/2$$ so substituting all these inequalities in the large equation in the answer above gives the term $2\varepsilon$. The key is that item **(a)** holds for *any* $\varepsilon$, so in particular for anything of the form $\varepsilon/2$, $\varepsilon^2$, etc...

Comment: (cont.) How large $x$ needs to be will depend, however, on your given $\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon/2$, $\varepsilon^2$, etc...